# Can someone help me out in lighttpd server facing issue in mod rewrite and 404 error in cms

Tags: web-server, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I am beginner in lighttpd I am facing problem in cms script because of htaccess as htaccess dont work in lighttpd I had enabled mod_rewrite in lighttpd.conf file
and due to this I am facing 404 error on web pages of my website
My .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
# Turn on URL rewriting

RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
# RewriteBase /
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

my lighttpd.conf (server module things only)

```
server. Modules = (
        "mod_magnet",
        "mod_indexfile",
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_rewrite",
        "mod_redirect",
#       "mod_rewrite",
        "mod_compress",
#       "mod_magnet",
        "mod_simple_vhost",
#       "mod_setenv",
#       "mod_rewrite",
        "mod_openssl",

)
```

please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your ".htaccess" file is not evaluated by lighttpd or any other webserver beside apache.

You have to write lines in different syntax in your lighttpd.conf

Examples:

```
url.rewrite = ( "^/status$" => "/server-status" )

url.redirect = ( "^/wishlist/(.+)" => "http://www.123.org/$1" )

deflate.mimetypes         = (
  "text/css; charset=utf-8",
  "text/css",
  "text/javascript; charset=utf-8",
  "text/javascript",
  "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  "text/plain",
  "text/html; charset=utf-8",
  "text/html"
)
```

Comment: lighttpd mod_deflate does a prefix match using the entries in `deflate.mimetypes`, so the additional charset=utf-8 is unnecessary (and syntactically does not match valid variants with spaces or not, and quotes like `"utf-8"`).  If appropriate, the above could be expanded and simplified into `deflate.mimetypes = ("text/")`